# ListView.setOnItemClickListener is not working when clicked on list item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a listview in Fragment Home and I want when Someone click on list item them new activity will open and data will pass to new activity and set to a text view. But nothing is happening when i click on list item

here is my Complete code of onItemClickListner

```
  public class Home extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
PostAdapter adapter;
TextView userId;
ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
//private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
DBHandler handler;
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_post, container, false);
    listView = (ListView)  view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        new DataFetcherTask().execute();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            userId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
            i.putExtra("userid", userId.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return view;

}

private class DataFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        String serverData = null;// String object to store fetched data from server
        // Http Request Code start
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://xyz.lt/json.php");
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            serverData = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.d("response", serverData);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Http Request Code end
        // Json Parsing Code Start
        try {
            postArrayList = new ArrayList<Post>();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverData);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObjectPOST = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String post_id = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_id");
                String user_id = jsonObjectPOST.getString("user_id");
                String user_name = jsonObjectPOST.getString("user_name");
                String post_title = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_title");
                String likes = jsonObjectPOST.getString("likes");
                String post_cat = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_cat");
                String post_time = jsonObjectPOST.getString("post_time");
                Post post = new Post();
                post.setPost_id(post_id);
                post.setUser_id(user_id);
                post.setUser_name(user_name);
                post.setPost_title(post_title);
                post.setLikes(likes);
                post.setPost_cat(post_cat);
                post.setPost_time(post_time);
                handler.addPost(post);// Inserting into DB
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        //Json Parsing code end
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        ArrayList<Post> postList = handler.getAllPost();
        adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new DataFetcherTask().execute();
    ArrayList<Post> postList = handler.getAllPost();
    adapter = new PostAdapter(getActivity(), postList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handler = new DBHandler(getActivity());
  new DataFetcherTask().execute();
}
}
```

I made an custom list item with images + textview + Image Buttons. I need just post_id then all the data will be fetched from sqlite using that text. Textview is initialized in PostAdapter where data is connected to list view.

after click this intent will open

```
public class PostView extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent!=null) {
        String stringData= intent.getStringExtra("userid");
        textView.setText(stringData);
    }
}
}
```

now just need to steup click listener on listview which perform his task. Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Which String value want to send?

Comment: row_userid from a textView

Answer (score 0):

Send data like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
    TextView userId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
    i.putExtra("userid", userId.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Get data like this in `PostView`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent!=null) {
    String stringData= intent.getStringExtra("userid");
}
```

Comment: but how to set string means how it will get value from textview

Comment: red underline , sorry exception

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. Check now.

Comment: still giving exception

Comment: what is the exception??

Comment: red underline at  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
                TextView userId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
                i.putExtra("row_userid", userId.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

Comment: text view is initialized in postAdapter not in this activity , So is it will work

Comment: Second parameter in the `onItemClick` is the view you clicked on. So yes it will work.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I returned view before listview.onClickListner but now exception is gone but click listner is not working when i cick on list item in emulator

Comment: Is it giving any error? Can you update your question and post the error if any?

Comment: when app is launched in emulator and I try to click on list item nothing happens

Comment: Could you update your question and post more code where you are setting the listener?

Comment: No. I meant code around `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {`. What is above it and what is below when this code block ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to send data,

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
    TextView userId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
    intent.putExtra("row_userid", userId.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And retrieve it like this,

```
String row_userid = getIntent().getStringExtra("row_userid");
```

Comment: red underline  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PostView.class);
                TextView userId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);
                i.putExtra("row_userid", userId.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

Comment: text view is initialized in postAdapter not in this activity , So is it will work

Comment: whole code of listview.onclicklistner is giving red underline

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I returned view before listview.onClickListner but now exception is gone but click listner is not working when i cick on list item in emulator

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:focusable="false" in your ImageButton in xml layout file. After that your ListView click listner will work

Answer (score 0):

When you use 
`userId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_userid);` 
You are using the `view` inside lister, rather you should be using `this.view` .